# two javascript codes on html page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have written two functions the first one must expand the article with the id "hope"
the second should make the image blobfish vanish but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I hope you can help me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .hidden {display:none;}
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p id="hope">My hope for you this year is that you will become a good                 problem solver.  
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="expandArt();">Click</a>
  </p>
 <img src="my_image/blobfish.jpg" id="ugly" onClick="makeInvisible();">
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function expandArt() {
      var expand = "My hope for you this year is that you will become a good  problem solver. Everyone will learn that they can figure out some tough answers  even when they feel stumped and frustrated in math, or reading, or at recess. Instead of giving up, you will say in your own mind, I can figure this out! I can do this.That's my hope for you.";
      document.getElementById("hope").innerHTML = expand;
}

  function makeInvisible() {
      document.getElementById("ugly").className = "hidden"; 
}

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `onclick` (all lowercase).

Comment: @pzp — HTML attribute names are case insensitive.

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/qeyuyiz/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score -1):

I have written a working example of the setup you have above, but one which uses an *unobtrusive javascript* approach. (ie. all the scripting remains between the `<script>` `</script>` tags and separated from the rest of the markup, rather than being scattered throughout the `html`.)

```js
function expandArticle() {
    var expandedText = 'My hope for you this year is that you will become a good  problem solver. Everyone will learn that they can figure out some tough answers even when they feel stumped and frustrated in math, or reading, or at recess. Instead of giving up, you will say in your own mind, I can figure this out! I can do this. That\'s my hope for you.';
    this.parentNode.innerHTML = expandedText;
}

function makeInvisible() {
    this.classList.add('hidden'); 
}

var hope = document.getElementsByClassName('hope')[0];
var hopeAnchor = hope.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
hopeAnchor.addEventListener('click',expandArticle,false);

var ugly = document.getElementsByClassName('ugly')[0];
ugly.addEventListener('click',makeInvisible,false);
```

```css
.hidden {
display:none;
}

.hope a {
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="hope">My hope for you this year is that you will become a good problem solver.  
<a>Click</a>
</p>

<img class="ugly" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
```